# What was this game show on UK Saturday morning TV?

Tags: story-identification

I am fairly certain that this show was part of "Live and Kicking" on Saturday mornings on BBC One in the late 1990s. It was a sci-fi themed game show with a team of children. They used a lift (I think) to travel around the various stages of the game. The antagonist, who was dressed in black, would move towards the lift if the team made too many mistakes. If the enemy reached the lift, then the game was over. I *think* the presenter, who also helped to guide the team, was John Barrowman.

Comment: Probably a better fit for [Movies & TV SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I was certain that it was a sci-fi themed show, that was why I asked it in this section of the site, and thought it would be alright to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly [Incredible Games](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0815403/) (1994-1995)

> Children's game show set in a personified lift called Sam. 'Crystal Maze' style games earned levels to get to the penthouse and try for the main prize.

> Incredible Games was a popular children's game show which was broadcast between 30 January 1994 and 14 March 1995 and aired on BBC1. It included a variety of games, performed by contestants between the ages of 10 and 13. The show itself was set in a fictional skyscraper (which was depicted in the titles by a London council tower block, Trellick Tower, in North Kensington) with a talking lift. In the first series, the lift was played by David Walliams, who later starred in Little Britain. In the second series, the lift was given a name, Sam, and was played by Gary Parker. Sam the Lift is popularly confused with the character played by Mark Speight in the CITV show Scratchy & Co..
>
> The aim of the show was to complete each game (set on a "floor" of the skyscraper), gradually rising up the tower. In the first series this climaxed in the alphabet soup game, and in the second series upon reaching the penthouse, where prizes could be won. In series two if a player lost a game, they were sent to the "basement" of the tower (the laundry room), and the other players had to take the lift back down to rescue them. In the first series the lift doors would open directly into game, whereas in the second series the lift doors would open to a generic corridor which had a series of doors, with a light above a door in the corridor indicating the relevant room. On occasions during the second series the lift door would open to reveal a darkened corridor with the dark knight walking slowly to the lift, which required the contestants to quickly shut the lift doors.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incredible_Games)</sup>

Comment: This was it :-) Barrowman must have been a guest on one episode. For some reason, him shouting at a group of children to close the lift door before the dark knight came was the only thing about this show I could rememeber :,)